# Python Selenium can't sendkeys (can't find input)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, element, sendkeys

I'm new to Python selenium and today I'm stuck with an element, I don't know why but I can't find the element and sendkeys. Can anyone please explain for me why i can't find it by id / xpath / css selector ? and Also how can we find it and sendkeys ?

Here is a screenshot of the element:

[image: The Element]

and the website is : **https://www.messenger.com/**

PS: I've tried java_execute_script but it doesn't work, I still don't know how to use it well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use python to write selenium program. I think you can press a key F12 and check the html code.

I help you to checked the class name. 
I checked the class name is `_1mf` , but I'm not sure what is your class name. You can check it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLfIB.png)

And then, you need to use the following code to finish it.

```
k=driver.find_element_by_class_name("_1mf")
k.send_keys('testing')
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
k.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

'testing' is my input element. You can change it.
'k' is my variable. You can change it.

I'm not sure is this a correct answer.

You can also reference the following videos:

```
https://www.largitdata.com/course/105/
https://www.largitdata.com/course/104/
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, i've already tried to find it by class name ( and yes we have the same class _1mf_1mj and it didn't work. Have you tried it on a python script ?

Comment: Not yet, when I see your situation. I think it is one of the method.

Comment: You can try to watch the videos, but I don't do you know Chinese~~Haha. You can see their code to learn it.

Comment: I tried it and it worked ! Thank you !
 Another small question, is facebook available in china ? As i know it's forbidden. It's not forbidden anymore or do you use a VPN ?

Comment: I live in Taiwan. Taiwan can use facebook. It is traditional Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below solution

```
inputBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='_kmc _7kpg navigationFocus']")))
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(inputBox).send_keys("Username").perform()
```

Note: Please add below import to your solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

[image]